# Problema con juego Pong: la AI no es fluida

Tags: javascript, html, html5, canvas, revisión-de-código

He desarrollado un juego Pong que tiene el siguiente código (comentado):

```js
//declar dos variables, canvas va a manejar toda la informacion de las dimenciones del area y canvasContext va a tener la informacion grafica como circulos triangulos y rectangulos
let canvas;
let canvasContext;
//variable para movimiento de la pelota
let ballX = 50;
let ballSpeedX = 10;
let ballY = 50;
let ballSpeedY = 4;
//movimiento del paddle
let paddle1Y = 250;
const PADDLE_HEIGHT = 100;
//paddle computadora derecho
let paddle2Y = 250;
const PADDLE_THICKNESS = 10;
//players score
let player1Score = 0;
let player2Score = 0;
const WINNING_SCORE = 6;
let winScreen = false;
//calcula la posicion del mouse (evt es resumen de evento)
function calculateMousePos(evt) {
  let rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  let root = document.documentElement;
  let mouseX = evt.clientX - rect.left - root.scrollLeft;
  let mouseY = evt.clientY - rect.top - root.scrollTop;
  return {
    x: mouseX,
    y: mouseY
  };

}

function handleMouseClick(evt) {
  if (winScreen) {
    player1Score = 0;
    player2Score = 0;
    winScreen = false;
  }
}
//cuando cargue la pagina,
window.onload = () => {
  canvas = document.getElementById('gameCanvas');
  canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');
  //con setInterval le digo que dibuje cada tanto tiempo en milisegundos
  let fps = 30;
  setInterval(() => {
    moveEverything();
    drawEverything();
  }, 1000 / fps);
  //click para continuar
  canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', handleMouseClick);
  //movimiento del paddle con el mouse 
  canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', evt => {
    let mousePos = calculateMousePos(evt);
    //alinea la posicion y del paddle al centro con el movimiento del mouse
    paddle1Y = mousePos.y - (PADDLE_HEIGHT / 2);
  });

}
//resetear la pelota
function ballReset() {
  if (player1Score >= WINNING_SCORE || player2Score >= WINNING_SCORE) {
    player1Score = 0;
    player2Score = 0;
    winScreen = true;
  }
  ballSpeedX = -ballSpeedX;
  ballX = canvas.width / 2;
  ballY = canvas.height / 2;
}
//computadora AI
function computerMovement() {
  //aca centramos el paddle 2, lo que dice paddle2y es donde esta el top, y paddle height lo edividimos por 2 para obtener el centro del paddle
  let paddle2YCenter = paddle2Y + (PADDLE_HEIGHT / 2);
  //si el paddle 2 esta por debajo de la pelota entonces subi 10 de lo contrario baja 10, lo que hace el ballY-35 y +35 es que ignore seguir la pelota mientras  esta35 pix arriba o debajo del paddle center pos
  if (paddle2YCenter < ballY - 35) {
    paddle2Y += 6;
  } else if (paddle2YCenter < ballY + 35) {
    paddle2Y -= 6;

  }
}
//funcion para mover la pelota y los jugadores
function moveEverything() {
  computerMovement();
  ballX += ballSpeedX;
  ballY += ballSpeedY;
  //lo que se calcula aca es que si la pelota esta rebotando o no contra el paddle
  if (ballX < 0) {
    if (ballY > paddle1Y && ballY < paddle1Y + PADDLE_HEIGHT) {
      ballSpeedX = -ballSpeedX;
      //le damos control a la pelota depende de donde rebote va a salir menos recta y con mas o menos velocidad
      let deltaY = ballY - (paddle1Y + PADDLE_HEIGHT / 2);
      ballSpeedY = deltaY * 0.35;
    } else {
      player2Score++;
      ballReset();
    }

  }
  if (ballX > canvas.width) {
    if (ballY > paddle2Y && ballY < paddle2Y + PADDLE_HEIGHT) {
      ballSpeedX = -ballSpeedX;
      let deltaY = ballY - (paddle2Y + PADDLE_HEIGHT / 2);
      ballSpeedY = deltaY * 0.35;
    } else {
      player1Score++;
      ballReset();
    }
  }

  if (ballY > canvas.height) {
    ballSpeedY = -ballSpeedY;
  }
  if (ballY < 0) {
    ballSpeedY = -ballSpeedY;
  }
}
//dinujar la red
function drawNet() {
  //vamos a usar un for que dice que la variable arranca en 0 y que suma de a 40 osea deja unos 40 pixeles de distancia
  for (let i = 0; i < canvas.height; i += 40) {
    colorRect(canvas.width / 2 - 1, i, 2, 20, 'white');

  }
}


// dibuja y usa la funcion colorRect para que este todo mas clean
function drawEverything() {
  //dibuja pantalla negra
  colorRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height, 'black');
  if (winScreen) {
    canvasContext.fillStyle = 'white';

    if (player1Score >= WINNING_SCORE) {
      canvasContext.fillText("Left Player Won", 350, 200);
    } else if (player2Score >= WINNING_SCORE) {
      canvasContext.fillText("Right Player Won", 350, 200);
    }

    canvasContext.fillText("click to continue", 350, 500);
    return;
  }

  drawNet();


  //paddle izq
  colorRect(0, paddle1Y, PADDLE_THICKNESS, PADDLE_HEIGHT, 'white');
  //paddle derecha
  colorRect(canvas.width - PADDLE_THICKNESS, paddle2Y, PADDLE_THICKNESS, PADDLE_HEIGHT, 'white');

  //dibuja la pelota
  colorCircle(ballX, ballY, 10, 'white');
  //mostrar el score
  canvasContext.fillText(player1Score, 100, 300);
  canvasContext.fillText(player2Score, canvas.width - 100, 300);

}
//funcion para resumir codigo para el paddle
function colorRect(leftX, topY, width, height, drawColor) {
  canvasContext.fillStyle = drawColor;
  canvasContext.fillRect(leftX, topY, width, height);
}
//resume codigo del circulo
function colorCircle(centerX, centerY, radius, drawColor) {
  //dibuja la pelota
  canvasContext.fillStyle = drawColor;
  //dibuja a la pelota redonda
  canvasContext.beginPath();
  canvasContext.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
  canvasContext.fill();
}
```

```html
<canvas id="gameCanvas" width="400" height="250"></canvas>
```

Pero quiero arreglar la AI del juego (que controla la raqueta de la derecha) porque funciona mal. En concreto, la siguiente parte del código creo que debería hacer que el paddle funcione mucho más fluido y no lo hace:

```
function computerMovement() {
    //aca centramos el paddle 2, lo que dice paddle2y es donde esta el top, y paddle height lo edividimos por 2 para obtener el centro del paddle
    let paddle2YCenter = paddle2Y + (PADDLE_HEIGHT/2);
    //si el paddle 2 esta por debajo de la pelota entonces subi 10 de lo contrario baja 10, lo que hace el ballY-35 y +35 es que ignore seguir la pelota mientras  esta35 pix arriba o debajo del paddle center pos
     if(paddle2YCenter < ballY - 35){
         paddle2Y += 20;
     }else if(paddle2YCenter > ballY + 35){
        paddle2Y -= 20;
     }
}
```

¿Cómo puedo cambiar el código para que funcione mejor y sea más fluido?

Comment: Hola. SO está enfocado en resolver problemas, no en hacer reviews de código, pues la respuesta aquí siempre será muy amplia. A menos que haya un problema específico que quieras resolver en tu código, creo que la pregunta no se ajusta al formato del sitio. Si no te aburre, está [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) en inglés para recibir feedback sobre tu código

Comment: function computerMovement() {
    //aca centramos el paddle 2, lo que dice paddle2y es donde esta el top, y paddle height lo edividimos por 2 para obtener el centro del paddle
    let paddle2YCenter = paddle2Y + (PADDLE_HEIGHT/2);
    //si el paddle 2 esta por debajo de la pelota entonces subi 10 de lo contrario baja 10, lo que hace el ballY-35 y +35 es que ignore seguir la pelota mientras  esta35 pix arriba o debajo del paddle center pos
     if(paddle2YCenter < ballY - 35){
         paddle2Y += 20;
     }else if(paddle2YCenter > ballY + 35){
        paddle2Y -= 20;

     }
}

Comment: resuleto en la ultima parte del codigo esta descubri ya el error

Comment: Si has descubierto el error tendrías que publicarlo y aceptar tu propia respuesta. Pienso que necesitas esperar 48 horas antes de aceptarla.

Comment: @pablocalofatti He editado un poco la publicación para mover los comentarios a la propia pregunta y que se adapte mejor al formato del sitio. Me imagino que la pregunta no tuvo una buena recepción porque las publicaciones que son sólo código se consideran de baja calidad al no tener un enunciado concreto (por lo que no son tan útiles para otros usuarios). Lee [ask] y completa el [tour] para más recomendaciones y aprender más sobre el sitio (y con eso ganarás una nueva medalla). Saludos

Comment: @pablocalofatti me alegro que consiguieses resolver el problema. Por favor, escribe una respuesta con lo que cambiaste para que funcionara al final (con una breve descripción del cambio para que así otros usuarios que puedan encontrarse con un problema similar, tengan una guía que seguir).

Comment: hola alvaroo disculpa soy nuevo en SO, me ayudas a publicar la respuesta?, a continuacion dejo la solucion en el siguyiente comentario

Comment: if(paddle2YCenter < ballY - 35){
         paddle2Y += 20;
     }else if(paddle2YCenter > ballY + 35){
        paddle2Y -= 20;
     }

Comment: en el comentario de arriba descubri que estaba bien por que se ve que lo publique luego de agregarlo pero en las pruebas me quedaba el con el codigo viejo por no actualizar el cache

Comment: en el codigo esta publicado de esta manera
  if (paddle2YCenter < ballY - 35) {
    paddle2Y += 6;
  } else if (paddle2YCenter < ballY + 35) {
    paddle2Y -= 6;
que es la incorrecta

Answer (score 2):

Algunos consejos:

1. Para `drawNet` puedes utilizar [contexto.setLineDash](http://w3.unpocodetodo.info/canvas/lineas-discontinuas.php).
2. Para la animación utilizaría [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame).
3. No olvides declarar `canvas.width` y `canvas.height`.
4. Si la posición de centro del paddle depende de la posición de la pelota, prueba `paddle2Y = ballY - PADDLE_HEIGHT/2`.
5. Haz que la pelota rebote también sobre la base y sobre el limite superior del canvas.
6. Considera parar la animación con `clearInterval` (por ejemplo) cuando se acaba el juego.